# Authentication of API Gateway methods using Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito, api-gateway

I have created a an API in API Gateway named “Test” which has 2 methods – add and delete.
Criteria:
Create 2 users in Cognito with 1st user having access to both methods and 2nd user having access to only “add”.

Can anyone help me in this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [using Groups with API Gateway docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html):

> You can use groups to create a collection of users in a user pool, which is often done to set the permissions for those users. For example, you can create separate groups for users who are readers, contributors, and editors of your website and app. Using the IAM role associated with a group, you can also set different permissions for those different groups so that only contributors can put content into Amazon S3 and only editors can publish content through an API in Amazon API Gateway.

You should be able to set permissions on the groups such that one has access to both API endpoints and the other just to the one.